# Apache Flink only produces partFiles

Tags: apache-flink

I am currentley trying to use the tableApi in apche flink and save streaming data as CSV files, but all I get is partFiles and not CSV-files.

My code look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable3 (
  transactionId STRING,
  timestamps STRING 
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'financial_transactions',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:29092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset'
  'format' = 'json'
);

CREATE TABLE fs_table2 (
  transactionId STRING 
) WITH (
  'connector'='filesystem',
  'path'='abfs://project@r.dfs.core.windows.net/data-project/data/output',
  'format'='csv',
  'sink.rolling-policy.file-size'='128MB',
  'sink.rolling-policy.rollover-interval'='2 min'
);

INSERT INTO fs_table2 SELECT transactionId FROM MyTable3;
```

all I get are these kind of partfiles: .part-0c9f9243-f9cc-4671-b734-0ba4185adf6e-0-1.inprogress.14ad1c71-15ec-470b-ac83-98a781e3afe4

How can I save it as real csv files?

I have tried all kinds of formats but always get these partFiles.

Comment: Have you enabled checkpointing?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to enable checkpointing for Flink to **finalise** the part-files , otherwise it'll be inprogress state indefinitely.

[As mentioned here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/#file-sink)

> IMPORTANT: Checkpointing needs to be enabled when using the FileSink in STREAMING mode. Part files can only be finalized on successful checkpoints. If checkpointing is disabled, part files will forever stay in the in-progress or the pending state, and cannot be safely read by downstream systems.

You can enable checkpointing using

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
// Set the checkpoint interval (e.g., every 5000 milliseconds)
env.enableCheckpointing(5000);

// Configure other checkpointing settings if needed
// env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(60000); // set checkpoint timeout
// env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1); // set max concurrent checkpoints
```

Comment: Yes, but even tho when I have enabled checkpoint the files still ends up in a strange file-format and not csv. If I open up the file I can see that it is CSV but the file in all is not of type CSV. This is the real issue I have, I want the file to end up as a file of typ CSV.

Comment: Manged to solve the issue! Thanks for the info regarding checkpointing!